# how can I fix this problem Host memory Low in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, backtrack

I install Backtrack 5 in virtualbox, and I get the error message Host Memory Low

[image]

Comment: Insert more memory, stop some other programs and/or decrease VM memory requirements (of this or other running VMs).

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to extend your virtual machine memory.
select your virtual machine and go to `setting > system` setting and change your memory size. 
[image]